# Why do I get several records in select using random function in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, resultset

This is my query:

```
SELECT id, geom from lars.punkt where id = (floor(random () * 99))::integer;
```

This is the result:

```
id    geom
40  "010100000000000000000010400000000000000000"
80  "010100000000000000000020400000000000000000"
88  "010100000000000000000020400000000000002040"
```

What is happening? I can also get 2 lines or zero lines.

I am expecting 1 line.

Is it the database which is "slow" or the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I am expecting 1 line.*

Random function is invoked per each row that is why you have zero, one or multiple matches. `CROSS JOIN` could be used to produce single random value that is used in `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT id, geom 
from lars.punkt 
CROSS JOIN(SELECT (floor(random () * 99)::integer)) s(c)  --generate single random value
where id = s.c;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo - run multiple times](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f936a29c43fc2ffbcc1ef18d1269c5fb)**

Comment: Just to be sure. For each row when DB make a comparison every function in the where clause  is run again.
Mening I hypothetically could get all the records in the output.
Is that for all or just some functions.

Comment: @Tengnagel "Is that for all or just some functions." It is for undeterministic functions.`Deterministic functions always return the same result any time they are called with a specific set of input values and given the same state of the database. Nondeterministic functions may return different results each time they are called with a specific set of input values even if the database state that they access remains the same. `